# Return type of bitwise operators in C++

Tags: c++, types, operators

As I'm implenting templated classes for small math vectors, I encounter one problem.
For the arithmetic operations, the return type of `T1 lhs + T2 rhs` is `std::common_type<T1, T2>::type.`
But what is the return type for the following (for example T1 signed and T2 unsigned or the contrary, or T1 char and T2 unsigned long long int etc...) :

```
T1 lhs & T2 rhs ?
T1 lhs | T2 rhs ?
T1 lhs ^ T2 rhs ?
T1 lhs << T2 rhs ?
T1 lhs >> T2 rhs ?
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you aware of the pitfalls inherent to performing bitwise functions on signed values?

Comment: Do you want to obtain that programmatically or do you want to know it? In the later case, declare (but not define) a template function with a single argument and call it with the expressions. The compiler will tell you the types in the error message

Comment: Unless I'm very mistaken (and I can be, oh yes) `<<` and `>>` depend only on the type of the lhs. (For built in types, that is.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are going to implement a compoment-wise bitwise operations on vectors. Essentially bitwise operations are integer operations and i see no reason why not to make their result as `std::common_type<T1, T2>::type`.

The result of shifts does not depend on the right operand. Just use T1 for it.

Comment: Because the result of shifts doesn't depend on the right hand side.